# Indexing several vectors per document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to compute the cosine similarity between paragraphs and search queries. However, the tutorials I find online seem to indicate that you can only have one vector per indexed document.. That is unfortunate for my use case since each document contains multiple paragraphs, and thus have multiple vectors associated with them.

So, when using similarity metrics like cosine similarity or k-nearest neighbors, what is the best way to deal with this? Do I add multiple JSONs per document to the index? That is, one for each vector?

Or, is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any limitations on count of vector fields per doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master//dense-vector.html); did you actually try to create a doc with 2 vector fields?

Comment: @ilvar Well, I may just be having a hard time wrapping my head around Elasticsearch; None of the examples show variable numbers of any field (I don't know how many paragraphs our documents may have since they vary in sizes from a page to hundreds). Are you saying that, in the examples in the doc, I can have multiple vectors like this?
PUT my-index/_doc/2
{
  "my_text" : "text2",
  "my_vector" : [-0.5, 10, 10],
  "my_vector": [1, 3, 4]
}

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do. Yes, this is not possible:

> Unlike most other data types, dense vectors are always single-valued. It is not possible to store multiple values in one dense_vector field.

You can have document per paragraph though.

Comment: @ilvar Okay, thank you.